# PHP - Jquery - Beginner - Am I doing it right?

Tags: php, jquery, security

I'm working on a small project and I've never used Jquery before. I would like to know if I'm on the right way before taking more steps.

**This is basicly my UI:**

```
 <ul id="Navigation">
      <li id="HomeButton">Home</li>
      <li id="NewsButton">News</li>
      <li id="AboutUsButton">AboutUsButton</li>
 </ul>

 <div id="Content"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#HomeButton").on("click", function(){
           $("#Content").load("pages/home.php");
      }); 
      $("#NewsButton").on("click", function(){
           $("#Content").load("pages/news.php");
      });  
      $("#AboutUsButton").on("click", function(){
           $("#Content").load("pages/asbout_us.php");
      });           
 </script>
```

Is this right way to build a dynamic jquery UI?

---

**This is basicly how I do database related stuff:**

*File name of an action:*

```
 clear_inventory.php
```

This code sets inventory slots to 0 in a database table and echo's the result.

*UI related to action:*

```
 <button id="ClearInventoryButton">Clear Inventory</button>

 <div id="ClearInventoryResult"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#ClearInventoryButton").one("click", function(){
           $("#ClearInventoryResult").load("actions/clear_inventory.php");
      });
```

Is this right / secure way to do it?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Sorry if the question was asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you should work on not being redundant and use a general selector like `class`, then use `this` to narrow the selection:

```
<ul id="Navigation">
      <li class="nav_btn" data-link="pages/home.php">Home</li>
      <li class="nav_btn" data-link="pages/news.php">News</li>
      <li class="nav_btn" data-link="pages/asbout_us.php">AboutUsButton</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#Navigation").on("click",".nav_btn", function(){
           window.location  =   $(this).data("link");
      });
</script>
```

As for your second question, you sound like you are talking about AJAX, that is unclear so I can not comment on that.

**EDIT: Regarding AJAX:**

You would need to do an ajax call using the `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.ajax` function like:

```
$("#ClearInventoryButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'actions/clear_inventory.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { reset: true }
            success: function(response) {
                    $("#ClearInventoryResult").html(response);
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about AJAX. Forgot to add it on title. :)

Comment: I have updated the basics of an ajax call, enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot. AJAX part realy helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the pages actually have. Firstly have a look at [the jQuery docs for Load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - it has complete handler which I would suggest you use. At the moment your code would work, bar the last snippet which has a "one" instead of "on".

I would make use of the completion & error handler, so if there is a problem server side with PHP and you get an error code you can process this. You could also load in fragments of a page with Load() - say you had two div's in home one called my account and other called overview, if someone clicked a new menu item 'overview' you could just load the home page and tell Load() to only take the overview div.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it out.